# How to properly add space in html

Tags: html

I have several input fields with similar name, to enable each input field entry to be sent on submission, I have added spacing after the name to make the names different, this is how they look:

```
<input type="text" id="name-one-input-id" name="Height" value="">
<input type="text" id="name-two-input-id" name="Height " value="">
<input type="text" id="name-three-input-id" name="Height  " value="">
<input type="text" id="name-four-input-id" name="Height   " value="">
```

It works okay but when submitted, the name of the input field has `%0a`, so it looks like `Height %0a`. what is the solution to remove `%0a`from the submited input field name?

Comment: Try look op on margin and padding for css

Comment: in what language are you parsing the result?, most certainly this is a bad practice, to differenciate name by spaces, replace them with numbers, postfix or anything else, this is bad from all points of view, from readability, usability, etc.

Comment: Change the spaces by numbers...`Height1, Height2, Height3, Height4`

Comment: Use array instead of sapce name="Height[]" this will sort your problem.

Comment: I want it to be just `height` in the submitted form, not `Height1, Height2, Height3....`

Comment: Which language do you use PHP ?

Comment: Yes, the language is php

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need multiple `input` elements with same name. You can have multiple elements with same name. Since you use `PHP`, You can use array syntax for name,

```
 <input type="text" id="name-one-input-id" name="Height[]" value="Nick">
 <input type="text" id="name-one-input-id" name="Height[]" value="James">
```

This will cause the browser to send over the form fields in a syntax that `PHP` will use to populate an array for these fields: `$_REQUEST['Height']`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name by adding numbers, just as you have with the ID of each input.
For example - *Height1, Height2, Height3 and Height4*

```html
<input type="text" id="name-one-input-id" name="Height1" value="">
<input type="text" id="name-two-input-id" name="Height2" value="">
<input type="text" id="name-three-input-id" name="Height3" value="">
<input type="text" id="name-four-input-id" name="Height4" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split remove it

```js
var a="Height %0a"
console.log(a.split(' %0a')[0])
```